# "dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules" warning

Tags: c++, warnings, strict-aliasing

I use a code where I cast an enum* to int*. Something like this:

```
enum foo { ... }
...
foo foobar;
int *pi = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&foobar);
```

When compiling the code (g++ 4.1.2), I get the following warning message:

```
dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
```

I googled this message, and found that it happens only when strict aliasing optimization is on. I have the following questions:

- If I leave the code with this warning, will it generate potentially wrong code?
- Is there any way to work around this problem?
- If there isn't, is it possible to turn off strict aliasing from inside the source file (because I don't want to turn it off for all source files and I don't want to make a separate Makefile rule for this source file)?

And yes, I actually need this kind of aliasing.

Comment: Why don't you just `static_cast<int>(foobar)`?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule/99010#99010) looks like it has what you are looking for.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In order:

- Yes. GCC will assume that the pointers cannot alias. For instance, if you assign through one then read from the other, GCC may, as an optimisation, reorder the read and write - I have seen this happen in production code, and it is not pleasant to debug.
- Several. You could use a union to represent the memory you need to reinterpret. You could use a `reinterpret_cast`. You could cast via `char *` at the point where you reinterpret the memory - `char *` are defined as being able to alias anything. You could use a type which has `__attribute__((__may_alias__))`. You could turn off the aliasing assumptions globally using -fno-strict-aliasing.
- `__attribute__((__may_alias__))` on the types used is probably the closest you can get to disabling the assumption for a particular section of code.

For your particular example, note that the size of an enum is ill defined; GCC generally uses the smallest integer size that can be used to represent it, so reinterpreting a pointer to an enum as an integer could leave you with uninitialised data bytes in the resulting integer. Don't do that. Why not just cast to a suitably large integer type?

Comment: Just a warning, that it's unspecified behaviour to use an union by writing to one member and reading from another, according to the C++ standard. So it may work, it may not.

Comment: @JPvdMerwe: GCC explicitly supports it though. So does MSVC.

Comment: "cast via `char*`" - your point isn't wrong, but "via" may be misleading. You can read the bytes one by one through a `char*` or `unsigned char*`. But `reinterpret_cast<int*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&foobar))` still breaks strict aliasing, even though I've "cast via `char*`". If X can alias Y, and Y can alias Z (Y being the `char*`), then under strict aliasing rules it does not necessarily follow that X can alias Z.

Comment: @JPvdMerwe: see accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511676/portable-data-reinterpretation

Comment: Avoiding the reinterpret_cast by static_casting to void* and then to the desired type will not produce the warning. Will it still invoke undefined behavior, though?

Comment: @antred: yes, it will.

Answer (score 13):

You could use the following code to cast your data:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
struct alias_cast_t
{
    union
    {
        F raw;
        T data;
    };
};

template<typename T, typename F>
T alias_cast(F raw_data)
{
    alias_cast_t<T, F> ac;
    ac.raw = raw_data;
    return ac.data;
}
```

Example usage:

```
unsigned int data = alias_cast<unsigned int>(raw_ptr);
```

Comment: Adding `static_assert(sizeof(T) == sizeof(F), "Cannot cast types of different sizes");` to `alias_cast` would improve safety of this code.

Comment: If this's used where T and F are pointer types, isn't this still UB?
And if they're non-pointer types, isn't this the same as `reinterpret_cast<T>(f)`, sans any additional checking?

Answer (score 11):

But why are you doing this? It will break if sizeof(foo) != sizeof(int). Just because an enum is like an integer does not mean it is stored as one.

So yes, it could generate "potentially" wrong code.

Comment: I checked, they are the same size.

Comment: @petersohn Maybe on your machine, that doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @petersohn: what about now? Are they still the same size? You have no guarantee that just because it worked at one point, it'll *keep* working.

Comment: @jalf: Yes, they're still the same size. It's implementation-defined what the underlying type of an enum is, not unspecified. I haven't actually checked GCC's docs on the subject, but I'm pretty sure they don't say, "int on Mondays, Wednesdays and Fridays but short on Tuesdays, Thursdays, weekends and public holidays". So I strongly suspect petersohn actually does have a guarantee, for the compiler he says he's using, possibly subject to changes from platform to platform. It's just that nobody has bothered to look it up and quote it.

Comment: I could manage to change the implementation so that now it is enough to static_cast between enum and int, not enum* and int*.

Comment: @Steve: true. :) @petersohn: that sounds much more sensible.

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule/99010#99010) ?

> The strict aliasing rule makes this
>   setup illegal, two unrelated types
>   can't point to the same memory. **Only
>   char* has this privilege**.
>   Unfortunately you can still code this
>   way, maybe get some warnings, but have
>   it compile fine.

Answer (score 3):

Strict aliasing is a compiler option, so you need to turn it off from the makefile.

And yes, it can generate incorrect code. The compiler will effectively assume that `foobar` and `pi` aren't bound together, and will assume that `*pi` won't change if `foobar` changed.

As already mentioned, use `static_cast` instead (and no pointers).