# Writing a double type value to a text file

Tags: c++, pointers, file-io

The below code is writing unreadable characters to the text file:

```
int main () 
{
    ofstream myfile ("example.txt");

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        double value       = 11.23444556;
        char   *conversion = (char *)&value;
        strcat (conversion, "\0");

        myfile.write (conversion, strlen (conversion));
        myfile.close();
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

I want to see the actual number written in the file :( Hints please.

**EDIT**
Seeing the answers below, I modified the code as:

```
int main () 
{
    ofstream myfile ("example.txt");

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        double value       = 11.23444556;

        myfile << value;
        myfile.close();
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

This produces the putput: **11.2344** while the actual number is **11.23444556**. I want the complete number.

**Editing the post to notify everyone:**
The unreadable characters are due to ofstream's write function:

> This is an unformatted output function

This quote is from: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/write/

Comment: @Anisha - The default is to display 6 digits, if you want a higher precision, you can do `myfile << setprecision(10) << value;` to get 10 digits in the number.

Comment: @Bo Persson: to get 10 digits in the number, `std::fixed` is also necessary, or else the trailing zeros willn't get printed.

Comment: Casting a double like that, other than wrong in this case, violates strict aliasing rule, so one way or the other your code wouldn't have worked.

Comment: @King_DuckZ So what's the correct way of casting?

Comment: You need to make a union with double and the type you want to cast to, or use memcopy. The latter on recent compilers should be optimized away and the resulting code would be exactly what you expect, but formally correct. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163126/c-dereferencing-type-punned-pointer-will-break-strict-aliasing-rules-warning

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Why don't you simply do this (updated answer after the edit in the question):

```
 #include <iomanip>

 myfile << std::fixed << std::setprecision(8) << value;
 myfile.close();
```

Now, you can see the actual number written in the file.

See the documentation of [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision). Note: you have to include the `<iomanip>` header file.

Comment: @Anisha: See it now. I updated it. Use `std::fixed` and `std::setprecision(8)`

Comment: Thanks, now it worked brilliantly! Can you tell WHAT was wrong with the original code?

Answer (score 3):

It's easier here to use the stream operators:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
    ofstream myfile ("example.txt");

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        double value       = 11.23444556;

        myfile << value;
        myfile.close();
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

gives you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Others suggested better ways but if you really want to do it the pointer way there should be casts to convert char* to double * and vice versa

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
  ofstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    double value       = 11.23444556;
    char     *conversion = reinterpret_cast<char *>(&value);
    strcat (conversion, "\0");
    //myfile.write (*conversion, strlen (conversion));
    myfile << *(reinterpret_cast<double *>(conversion));
    myfile.close();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the value to file like this:

```
myfile << value;
```

Using the adress of value as parameter `strcat` corrupts your stack, since `strcat` expects a 0-terminated c-string as first argument (and actually allocated space).