# Type punning, char[] and dereferencing

Tags: c++, type-punning

I have a structure which aims at storing user defined data (i.e. from a plugin). It has a such a `char[]` with a given maximum size to store that data.

```
struct A
{
    // other members omitted
    // data meant to be type punned, only contains PODs
    char data[256];
};
```

Then there's a sample user structure that has a static function to cast itself from `A`.

```
struct B
{
    int i;
    double d;

    static B& FromA_ref(A& a)
    {
        // static_assert that sizeof(B) < sizeof(A::data)
        return * reinterpret_cast<B*>(a.data);
    }
};
```

I compile with `g++ -O3 -std=c++0x -Wall -o test test.cpp` (GCC 4.6.1).

This triggers a `dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules` warning. I thought that would be ok since I have used a `char[]` as storage which I thought would follow the same rules as `char*`. I find it strange that it doesn't. Don't you ? Well, ... I can't change it right now, so let's move on.

Now let's consider the following method:

```
struct B
{
    ....
    static B* FromA_ptr(A& a)
    {
        // static_assert that sizeof(B) < sizeof(A::data)
        return reinterpret_cast<B*>(a.data);
    }
}
```

Since I am not dereferencing anything here GCC doesn't output any warning. Neither does it when I use my pointer to `B` later on.

```
A a;
auto b = B::FromA_ptr(a);
b->i = 2; // no warnings.
```

**But is it safe to do so ?** I feel like I have been working my way around the problem rather than solving it. For me `->` is still dereferencing the variable somehow.

Alternatively, are there any better way to achieve the effect ? I.E. get a modifiable reference (or pointer) casted from a storage inside another struct ? (Union won't work since the set of types stored are not known when `A` is defined and some may be added via plug-ins, `memcpy` will force me to copy the data back and forth though it seems to be the only safe way so far)

Comment: I'm no expert, but are you looking for the `__may_alias__` attribute? http://blog.worldofcoding.com/2010/02/solving-gcc-44-strict-aliasing-problems.html

Comment: Anyway, how do you deal with the alignment issue?

Comment: @curiousguy : so far I don't but I should. On x86 I guess that I may degrade the performance at worst, though. I hope `__attribute__((aligned(8)));` would be enough since I am not trying to auto vectorize anything. Probably, `may_alias` already tells GCC to pay attention to alignment before doing too much weird stuff.

Comment: @curiousguy: A simple approach should be `union { char dat[theSize]; typeWithWorstAlignment dummy; }`.  That would take care of everything but aliasing issues, for which the Standard offers no solution.  Given the lack of any solution to aliasing issues, I find it odd that the C11 Standard included alignment directives which aren't really useful *except* in circumstances involving type punning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no, it is not safe (see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163126/c-dereferencing-type-punned-pointer-will-break-strict-aliasing-rules-warnin))

> GCC will assume that the pointers cannot alias. For instance, if you assign through one then read from the other, GCC may, as an optimisation, reorder the read and write - I have seen this happen in production code, it is not pleasant to debug.
>
> **attribute**((**may_alias**)) on the types used is probably the closest you can get to disabling the assumption for a particular section of code.