# Should I worry about compiler warnings in Boost with -O3?

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-warnings

I've found that a multi-threaded program I created with Boost is much faster when I activate the -O3 flag. However, that raises some extra compiler warnings, all of which say the following:

```
warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
```

These warnings are all generated in the Boost file `shared_mutex.hpp`. To be concrete, the following function is causing these warnings:

```
template<typename T>
T interlocked_compare_exchange(T* target,T new_value,T comparand)
{
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(T)==sizeof(long));
    long const res=BOOST_INTERLOCKED_COMPARE_EXCHANGE(reinterpret_cast<long*>(target),
                                                      *reinterpret_cast<long*>(&new_value),
                                                      *reinterpret_cast<long*>(&comparand));
    return *reinterpret_cast<T const*>(&res);
}
```

From looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4163126/1560509), it looks like these warnings mean that the code can crash, but that seems unlikely coming from a Boost file. Now, my program has become quite complex, and I have seen it (on rare and seemingly random instances) crash when running for long periods of time. Is it possible that the Boost library is causing this? If it matters, I'm using mingw.

Comment: Anything is possible but I would check your code before boosts, boost's code is tested by the multitude of people that use it, your code is only tested by you, which one is more likely to be correct?

Comment: @aaronman: yet if that code is in the `shared_mutex.hpp` in the boost distribution then the warning is not in *his* code... and the warning does look legit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should worry about the strict-aliasing warnings! The compiler will actually make assumptions that there is no alias to an object which will cause problems. If your code (or code you use) isn't aliasing-clean, you should disable the corresponding option:

```
-fno-strict-aliasing
```

It is quite common that this particular optimization is explicitly disabled because a lot of code actually violates the strict-aliasing rules.

Answer (score 0):

That issue has already been reported to boost [here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7765), and the warning is legit. If that code is inlined in the calling function, the compiler is conceptually allowed to reorder access through those `reinterpret_cast` and through the original variable.

That being said, this is in an specific piece of code that is using atomic operations, so the expansion of the BOOST_INTERLOCKED_COMPARE_EXCHANGE macro probably includes guards to block the compiler and the cpu from reordering the instructions... so it may be fine.